# Unable to get a Span<Type> from all types in an assembly

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to get all the types in an assembly (`assembly.GetTypes()`) and I try to get a span from that without any heap-allocation which would look like this `assembly.GetTypes().AsSpan()`. However the weird thing is that this throws the following error:

> System.ArrayTypeMismatchException: 'Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.'

Which kinda confused me, what made it even more confusing is that `assembly.GetTypes().ToArray().AsSpan()` runs without any issues, but this obviously isn't a solution.

A fiddle, which shows this can be found right [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jI46uo).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`assembly.GetTypes()` returns a `RuntimeType[]`, but it uses array type covariance to disguise it as a `Type[]`. Per the docs for the [`Span` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1.-ctor?view=netcore-3.1#System_Span_1__ctor__0___), an `ArrayTypeMismatchException` is thrown if `T` (which in this case is `Type`) does not match the runtime array type (which in this case is `RuntimeType`).

`assembly.GetTypes().ToArray()` on the other hand returns an actual `Type[]`: it will create a *brand new* array based on the declared type `T`, which is `Type`, so you get a true `Type[]` array and there is no mismatch -- `T` is `Type` and you're passing a true `Type[]` to the `Span` constructor.

`ReadOnlySpan<T>` does not have this constraint, since it is not possible to write an incompatible `Type` to a read-only `RuntimeType[]`, so you can do this:

```cs
new ReadOnlySpan<Type>(assembly.GetTypes());
```

Comment: And RuntimeType is not public, so casting it back to not have to copy the array is not possible (just trying to find a solution not involving copying the array)

Comment: I mean this defiantly makes sense, even if this is indeed a bit of a pain in the ass since no matter what I'd do, I couldn't directly create a span from this array huh?

Comment: Feels like this should be documented on the `AsSpan` method.

Comment: @Twenty I've updated my answer with an alternative that might work for you. If you're not going to be writing anything to the span, then you can use a `ReadOnlySpan` which won't throw.

Comment: @Jeff Oh that actually makes it a lot easier than expected, luckily I don't modify the array, so thanks a lot!